# error in create data source for sqlserver in wso2 ei

Tags: wso2, dataservice, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

after installing wso2 ei, i download sql server jdbc driver and copy it in wso2home/lib, i want to create service via sql query so i define below data service :

```
<data name="BankDB" transports="http https local">
<config enableOData="false" id="sql">
  <property name="dataSourceClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="dataSourceProps">
     <property name="url">jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433/databaseName=ApiDB</property>
     <property name="username">username</property>
     <property name="password">password</property>
  </property>
</config>
<query id="MappedFaults" useConfig="sql">
  <sql>select BankCode from ApiDB.dbo.MappedFaults</sql>
  <result element="BankCode" rowName="">
     <element column="BankCode" name="BankCode" namespace="BankCode" xsdType="string"/>
  </result>
</query>
<operation name="select">
  <call-query href="MappedFaults"/>
</operation>
</data>
```

but i get this error :

```
DS Fault Message: Error creating JDBC Pool SQL Config: Error in creating external data source: Setter method for property 'password' cannot be found DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR Source Data Service:- Name: BankDB Location: \BankDB.dbs Description: N/A Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice Nested Exception:- org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error in creating external data source: Setter method for property 'password' cannot be found at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.JDBCPoolSQLConfig.getDataSource(JDBCPoolSQLConfig.java:66) at
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what is wrong here but looking at comparable configurations I think the username and password are not part of 'dataSourceProps'. I would suggest though to create a datasource manually and just reference it like so:  <config id="default">
  <property name="carbon_datasource_name">ApiDB_datasource</property>
 </config>

Comment: i change config section to  <config enableOData="false" id="1">
      <property name="dataSourceClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;databaseName=ApiDB</property>
      <property name="username">username</property>
      <property name="password">password</property>
   </config> and now get this error : DS Fault Message: DataSource is of unknown class:class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver DS Code: CONNECTION_UNAVAILABLE_ERROR Source Data Service:- Name: APIDB

Comment: i added sqljdbc.jar in wso2home/bin and run project but get above error

Comment: in wso2 dataservice it is ok when i copy jar files in wso2dsshome/repository/compounents/lib and it is ok but in wso2eihome we haven't this root

Comment: I think you can copy the jar into <wso2ei-6.1.1>/lib

Comment: Ah, but why not first create a datasource as shown here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Datasource+Configuration+Parameters and then use this in your service? This allows for easier configuration and also a 'test' button that tests basic connectivity.